# How to publish trimmed windows forms application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have Windows Forms application and want to publish it as self-contained and trim it.
But when I run

```
dotnet new winforms
dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64 --self-contained /p:PublishTrimmed=true
```

I receive following error

```
error NETSDK1175: Windows Forms is not supported or recommended with trimming enabled.
Please go to https://aka.ms/dotnet-illink/windows-forms for more details.
```

My application is pretty simple, and I do not think that I will hit any issues with trimming.

Answer (score 10):

Just add `<_SuppressWinFormsTrimError>true</_SuppressWinFormsTrimError>` to your project file. That allow bypass that safeguard, and have trimmed application.

That's helpful if you want publish you application using NativeAOT for example. Also please be aware, that this is still unsupported area, and you may hit some unexpected issues.

Comment: btw, for WPF similar flag is _SuppressWpfTrimError